# Factoring symmetric polynomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Find all solutions $a, b, c, \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$ of

$$a + b + c + ab + bc + ca = abc + 1$$

Moving everything to the left hand side, we get

$$a + b + c + ab + bc + ca - abc - 1 = 0$$

We can write this as a polynomial in $a, b, c$:

$$f(a, b, c) = a + b + c + ab + bc + ca - abc - 1$$

Now, solving the equation is equivalent to finding the roots of the above polynomial. Observe that

$$f(-1, -1, -1) = -3 + 3 + 1 - 1 = 0$$

Therefore, $(a+b+c+3)$ is a factor of $f(a, b, c)$. I tried dividing the polynomial but it quickly became too complicated to handle. I noticed that this was symmetric in $a, b, c$. I'm pretty sure this problem doesn't involve brute calculation. There must be a more elegant (that is, lazy) way to factor this polynomial. And in general, factor all symmetric polynomials.

Comment: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/70347.html

Comment: In one variable the irreducible polynomials are only $x-r$. Given a root, the minimal polynomial that has that root is irreducible. So when a polynomial of one variable vanishes at $r$, then it is divisible by the minimum polynomial there is that has that root. This is $x-r$. For more than one variable, there are many irreducible polynomials that vanish at a given point $(-1,-1,-1)$ of the plane. Having a polynomial vanishing at a point doesn't imply it is going to be divisible by any particular one of these irreducibles.

Comment: @ABC: But, let's say that $f(a, b, c) = (a+b+c+3)q(a, b, c) + r$. Clearly, $f(-1, -1, -1) = 0 = r$. This is the proof for the factor theorem.

Comment: @Gerard All you have shown is $r(-1, -1, -1)=0$.

Comment: What if the factor were $1+abc$ ? It is symmetrical, and it would be a zero of your polynomial.(Just following Macavity here)

Comment: @Gerard in the factor theorem you work with the fact that you have one variable. The degree of $r$ in that variable is smaller than the divisor. If the divisor is of degree one then $r$ would be a constant and by your argument it would be zero. But in several variables you could have $f=(a+b+c+3)q(a,b,c)+(1+b)$. Maybe the degree of $r=1+b$, in the variable $a$ is smaller than that of $a+b+c+3$, but still $1+b$ is not a constant. As you can see, $a+b+c+3$ and $1+b$ are two different irreducible polynomials that both vanish at $(-1,-1,-1)$.